# How do I get an Android image and put it on the WebView?

Tags: javascript, java, android, spring

My web is currently configured with spring frame workloads. What I want to do is take an `image` of Android and float it on the `Web`.

Importing `Android images` will be done using `Android` image selection modules.

Is this possible?

And I have to save it as an `image file` on the server. Is this possible?

Controller that stores current image files

```java
    @RequestMapping(value="/profile_image", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public @ResponseBody Map<String, Object> profile_image(HttpServletRequest webRequest
            , @RequestParam(value="image", required=false) MultipartFile image

        Map<String, String> param = new HashMap<String, String>();
        Map<String, Object> result = new HashMap<String, Object>();
 try {

            // The image has been updated.
            String imagePath = "";
            if (image != null) {
                String Extension =  Config.USER_PROFILE_IMAGE_EXT;
                String fileName = "user_profile_"+ user_nickname + Utils.getCurrentTime("yyyyMMddHHmmssSSS");
                imagePath = Define.CONTENTS_FILE_PATH_4 + fileName + Extension ;

                File saveDir = new File(Define.CONTENTS_SAVE_PATH + Define.CONTENTS_FILE_PATH_4);
                if (!saveDir.isFile()) saveDir.mkdirs();

                image.transferTo(new File(Define.CONTENTS_SAVE_PATH + imagePath));

                String fileName_thumbnail = fileName + "_thumb" + Extension;
                File thumbnail = new File(Define.CONTENTS_SAVE_PATH + Define.CONTENTS_FILE_PATH_4 + fileName_thumbnail);

                thumbnail.getParentFile().mkdirs();
                Thumbnails.of(saveDir + "/" + fileName + Extension).size(Config.USER_PROFILE_IMAGE_WIDTH, Config.USER_PROFILE_IMAGE_HEIGHT).outputFormat("jpg").toFile(thumbnail);
            }

            param.put("imagepath", (!imagePath.equals("")) ? Define.PLATFORM_SERVER_HOST_NAME + imagePath : "");

            if (backOfficeDao.update_user_profile_image(param) < 1) {
                result.put("resultMsg", "Databases update fail..");

            } else {
                result.put("resultMsg", "Shop successful in modifying product information.");
            }


        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            result.put("resultCode", Define.ERROR_CODE_001);
            result.put("resultMsg", "[ERROR] Server error");
        }

        return result;

    }
```

I should take the `picture` from the `device store`, place it in `WebView`, send the `Image file` to the `WebService` and save it to the server.

[image]

Thanks you in advance

Comment: Do you need to take a photo from the device storage and put it on a WebView or send it to a WebService? It´s not so clear what you are asking, could you please provide a little bit more detail on what you need? Thanks

Comment: Hi @axierjhtjz Yes,I should take the picture from the device store, place it in WebView, send the file to the WebService and save it to the server.

Comment: Your webview will only show the image or it shows a UI of some type? If you only need to display the image, you can load a base64 into the webview. Else, you will need to use a JavascriptInterface to load the image.

Comment: What is the method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sends file data via communication with the server in the mutipart type from Android, which saves the file from my controller, reads the data that I saved, and refreshes it, allowing the user to view the image file data that they have imported.